# Творення слова "Нівроку" та його виникнення

Tags: етимологія, прислівники

Академічний тлумачний словник вичерпно пояснює значення слова, у різних аспектах. 
http://sum.in.ua/s/nivroku
А мене цікавить його походження та словотворення, де можна знайти вичерпну інформацію.

Answer (score 5):

«Нівроку» – результат злиття заперечної частки *ні* та *[уро́ки](http://sum.in.ua/s/uroky)* (*вро́ки*) (у формі род. в. однини) «наслання хвороби поглядом».

«Уро́ки» ж разом із «навро́чити» походить від «[ректи́](http://sum.in.ua/s/rekty)» – говорити, мовити, промовляти

<sup>Джерело інформації про «нівроку»: [Етимологічний словник української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm): У 7 т. / Редкол. О. С. Мельничук (голов. ред.) та ін. — К.: Наук. думка, 1983 — . — ISBN 966-00-0816-3. 

[Т. 4](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.djvu): Н — П / Уклад.: Р. В. Болдирєв та ін.; Ред. тому: В. Т. Коломієць, В. Г. Скляренко. — 2003,  сторінка **95**.</sup>